# Redis writing to .ssh/authorized_keys

Tags: security, redis

current setup, 
2 master servers, 12 worker servers:
workers are connected to master through ssh-copy-id, masters and workers are writing data in redis-queues on masters.
issue i have been facing for past week is that redis is writing data in the authorized_keys file, i cant reproduce this issue or confirm which server is doing this.
I looked into the redis config file and i didn't find any setting that would make redis write in authorized_keys file.
Has anyone else faced this issue or similar, i clear the authorized keys file and it writes into it again.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Your servers are most probably being/have been attacked by a "cracker". While it is possible that attack is over, you should treat your servers as compromised and act accordingly. This is in all likelihood the same approach described by Salvatore Sanfilippo a.k.a antirez, Redis' author and security researcher in his past, in [this blog post](http://antirez.com/news/96).

To prevent this type of attacks which use Redis as a vector, please refer to the instructions in the [Securing Redis](http://redis.io/topics/quickstart#securing-redis) in the Quicktart page as a starting point and the [Security](http://redis.io/topics/security) page for more information.

More discussion is at [/r/redis](https://www.reddit.com/r/redis/comments/3rby8c/a_few_things_about_redis_security/)

Update: more ramblings on the same topic at https://redislabs.com/blog/3-critical-points-about-security

Comment: This was probably integrated already into all popular botnets/pentest tools/whatever. :)

Comment: hi, might helpful, just checked the 2 master servers running redis server, some guy changed rsa keys, root password changed, so reinstalled servers. i'll accept this as the answer, and will start a new thread if i face any issues with security implementation