# redis rewrites the dir and dbfilename automatically

Tags: redis, config

Recently, I got some weird things while using redis-2.8.19.
I used redis as memory queues, and my program ran well for some months,
so I checked the server log, it said:

```
[19167] 21 Nov 13:49:24.022 * 10 changes in 300 seconds. Saving...

[19167] 21 Nov 13:49:24.023 * Background saving started by pid 15912

[15912] 21 Nov 13:49:24.100 # Error moving temp DB file on the final 
destination: Is a directory

[19167] 21 Nov 13:49:24.123 # Background saving error
```

so, I used commands `:echo "CONFIG GET *" | redis-cli | grep -e "dir" -e "dbfilename" -A1`, 
and it showed as following:

```
dbfilename
authorized_keys
--
dir
/root/.ssh
```

Naturally, I changed the `dir` and `dbfilename` config and restarted the redis, the program ran well for some hours or some days before broken down again for the same reason. I checked the dir and dbfilename config and found them written exactly same as before. The redis process never restart during the period and no one may change the config.

So I just get confused, how the `dir` and `dbfilename` config changed?

Comment: Have you seen [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33692230/redis-writing-to-ssh-authorized-keys)?

Comment: appreciate for ur comment, it's very helpful.It has great possibilities that the redis server got hacked. And I will take some measures to raise redis security level

Comment: BTW, in my situation, the 'authorized_keys' is a directory instead of a file , is there any chance that redis create the directory instead of a file when the dbfilename is 'authorized_keys', so it can warn the users that the redis has been hacked?

Comment: The `authorized_keys` hack described in the earlier post is just one of several possibilities, and guarding against it alone will not secure your system. Be sure to read http://redis.io/topics/security before deploying Redis in production.